# Convert String of letters to numbers according to ordinal value?

Tags: python, string, integer, ordinal

I have no idea where to start with this. I need to write a function that will return a string of numbers in ordinal value. So like

```
stringConvert('DABC')
```

would give me `'4123'`

```
stringConvert('XPFT')
```

would give me `'4213'`

I thought maybe I could make a dictionary and make the each letter from the string associate it with an integer, but that seems too inefficient and I still don't know how to put them in order.

Answer (score 2):

You could sort the unique characters in the input string and apply indices to each letter by using the [`enumerate()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
def stringConvert(s):
    ordinals = {c: str(ordinal) for ordinal, c in enumerate(sorted(set(s)), 1)}
    return ''.join([ordinals[c] for c in s])
```

The second argument to `enumerate()` is the integer at which to start counting; since your ordinals start at 1 you use that as the starting value rather than `0`. [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) gives us the unique values only.

`ordinals` then is a dictionary mapping character to an integer, in alphabetical order.

Demo:

```
>>> def stringConvert(s):
...     ordinals = {c: str(ordinal) for ordinal, c in enumerate(sorted(set(s)), 1)}
...     return ''.join([ordinals[c] for c in s])
... 
>>> stringConvert('DABC')
'4123'
>>> stringConvert('XPFT')
'4213'
```

Breaking that all down a little:

```
>>> s = 'XPFT'
>>> set(s)  # unique characters
set(['X', 'F', 'T', 'P'])
>>> sorted(set(s))  # unique characters in sorted order
['F', 'P', 'T', 'X']
>>> list(enumerate(sorted(set(s)), 1))  # unique characters in sorted order with index
[(1, 'F'), (2, 'P'), (3, 'T'), (4, 'X')]
>>> {c: str(ordinal) for ordinal, c in enumerate(sorted(s), 1)}  # character to number
{'P': '2', 'T': '3', 'X': '4', 'F': '1'}
```

Comment: You can pass the generator directly to `str.join`. No need to create the list first. I.e., `''.join(ordinals[c] for c in s)`

Comment: @PeterSutton: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024); `str.join()` is the **one** place where using a list comprehension is going to be more efficient; to join the string the iterable has to be converted to a list otherwise anyway so as to scan it twice.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. But can you explain to me what you did here. I'm fairly new to python and this is the first time I encountered the enumerate and sorted sets part.

Comment: @EdwardStark: try out the different parts in the interpreter. `set()` produces a collection of letters that is unique; so `set('aaaaaa')` gives you `set(['a'])`, just the one letter `a`, etc. `sorted()` produces a new list with values from the input, sorted.

Comment: @EdwardStark: `enumerate()` produces `(index, value)` tuples as you iterate. So for the input `'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'` the output `(1, 'a')`, `(2, 'b')`, `(3, 'c')`, `(4, 'd')` is produced. The dictionary comprehension takes those pairs and maps the character to the number (converted to a string here because that's the output you wanted).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `string` module, especially [maketrans](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans) and [translate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate)

With those, your code may look like

```
def stringConvert(letters):
    return translate(letters, maketrans(''.join(sorted(set(letters))).ljust(9), '123456789'))
```

and pass your strings as variable

Comment: What if `letters` is longer or shorter than 4 characters? What if characters are repeated?

Comment: Changed answer to this requirements

Comment: I like the use of the hardcoded digits, nice touch! Do add a note that this limits your solution to just 9 unique characters in the input.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a character translation table and use the `translate()` string method:

```
from string import maketrans

TO = ''.join(str(i+1)[0] for i in xrange(256))

def stringConvert(s):
    frm = ''.join(sorted(set(s)))
    return s.translate(maketrans(frm, TO[:len(frm)]))

print stringConvert('DABC')  # --> 4123
print stringConvert('XPFT')  # --> 4213
```

Comment: Because you are already heavily leaning on `sorted()` and using `str.join()`, any advantage `str.translate()` may have had has evaporated.

Comment: @Martijn: Good point, but moving the creation of the translation's "TO" string outside of the function -- since its a constant except for its length -- makes up for that and the result is faster than your version in a benchmark I setup and ran: `martineau : 2.808794 secs, rel speed 1.000000x` vs `Martijn Pieters : 5.143616 secs, rel speed 1.831254x` for 1,000,000 calls each, best of 3.

Comment: Yup, you are now using the same approach as Slam; predefine the target mapping.